# Using 1 Query to Display COUNT(Items) in a Column and COUNT(Same Item, but With Certain Value in Another Column)

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

I have three tables in a dummy database: inventory, film, and rental.

I need to know which film titles are not in the inventory. The only way to answer this that I can think of is by counting each item in the inventory and then comparing that count to the number of the same item that haven't been returned.

This returns three columns:

```
    SELECT film.title, COUNT(inventory.film_id), (SELECT COUNT(inventory.film_id)
                                                  FROM inventory
                                                  INNER JOIN rental ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
                                                  INNER JOIN film on film.film_id = inventory.film_id
                                                  WHERE rental.return_date IS NULL)
    FROM inventory
    INNER JOIN rental ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
    INNER JOIN film on film.film_id = inventory.film_id
    GROUP BY film.title
```

Output:

```
"Graceland Dynamite"    "6" "183"
"Opus Ice"  "11"    "183"
"Braveheart Human"  "5" "183"
"Wonderful Drop"    "9" "183"
...
```

As you can see, it shows me in the last column the TOTAL number of non-returned DVD's, while I want the total for that column.

If I run it and just look for the inventory count like so:

```
    SELECT film.title, COUNT(inventory.film_id)
    FROM inventory
    INNER JOIN rental ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
    INNER JOIN film on film.film_id = inventory.film_id
    GROUP BY film.title
```

That works:

```
"Graceland Dynamite"    "6"
"Opus Ice"  "11"
"Braveheart Human"  "5"
...
```

And if I run the same thing but counting only the inventory that has a NULL return date:

```
    SELECT film.title, COUNT(inventory.film_id), rental.return_date
    FROM inventory
    INNER JOIN rental ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
    INNER JOIN film on film.film_id = inventory.film_id
    WHERE rental.return_date IS NULL
    GROUP BY film.title, rental.return_date
```

That works too:

```
"Theory Mermaid"    "1" 
"Dances None"   "2" 
"Bound Cheaper" "1" 
...
```

Please let me know if you can help me understand how to return the inventory count in one column and also the count of the non-returned items, and bonus points if you can tell me how to have a column that shows the difference between the two.

Also if there's a way to return only the rows where the difference is zero, that would be cool.

OR if I'm just thinking about this all wrong let me know too! I need all the help I can get.

Thanks!!

UPDATE:

I tried it like this too:

```
    SELECT film.title, COUNT(inventory.film_id), x.copies_out
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(rental.inventory_id) as copies_out
          FROM rental
          WHERE rental.return_date IS NULL) as x, inventory
    INNER JOIN film ON film.film_id = inventory.film_id
    INNER JOIN rental ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
    GROUP BY film.title, x.copies_out, rental.inventory_id
    HAVING COUNT(inventory.film_id) <= x.copies_out
```

This returns me 3 columns, one with the film title, one with the number of total copies listed in inventory, and one with the total number of rentals that still have not been returned (not the number of rentals with that inventory ID that haven't been returned yet.)

```
"Giant Troopers"    "5" "183"
"Confessions Maguire"   "2" "183"
"Vacation Boondock" "3" "183"
```

Please help!
-Pete

Comment: Why does the `rental` table have any significance here?  Is the absence of a film in the `inventory` table enough to answer your question?

Comment: Any chance you could provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) with some data and your desired result? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: your question is not clear  .,.. and too  broad  ..  you should post a questiion but time not several question in one post .. and for a single question you should add  also  the expected  result as data sample not by words ..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the inventory table only lists the DVD's that exist, not which ones are or are not currently rented. The only way to show if a DVD were not in stock would be to show that all copies are currently being rented and haven't been returned, meaning that they have NULL in the rental return_date category.

Comment: Thanks guys, the answer below cleared it up for me. I hadn't been aware of FILTER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a conditional aggregation using the `filter` clause:

```
SELECT film.title, 
       count(inventory.film_id), 
       count(distinct rental.inventory_id) filter (where rental.return_date is null) 
FROM inventory
  INNER JOIN rental ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
  INNER JOIN film on film.film_id = inventory.film_id
GROUP BY film.title;
```

Comment: Thanks! That displays the comparison I'm looking for. Now in theory this sounds simple... but do you know how to have it return a column that displays only rows where the filtered rental.inventory_id count is greater than the inventory.film_id count?

Comment: Actually, I got it--just adding a simple "HAVING" clause, if I'm correct. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know which film titles are not in the inventory.

This sounds like `not exists`:

```
select f.*
from films f
where not exists (select 1
                  from inventory i
                  where i.film_id = f.film_id
                 );
```

The `rental` table is not needed for this query.

If you need the `rental` table to identify films in the inventory, then you cannot answer your question.  The closest you can come is "What films have not been rented?"  That would be:

```
select f.*
from films f
where not exists (select 1
                  from inventory i join
                       rental r
                       on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
                  where r.film_id = f.film_id
                 );
```